# Unity - How to put an animation onto the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 questions

1) How do I put this animation, `Player_Idle` onto the scene? I tried dragging it onto screen but didn't work.

[image: Cannot drag animation]

2) How can I copy all the components from `player` Gameobject onto the new animation (once it's on screen)?

[image: Components of Player GameObject]

Comment: You can't "put an animation in the scene". You can only add an animation to either an `Animation` component or inside an `Animator state machine`.

Comment: This is not how animations work. You need animaTOR component on the object which can play animations. Have a look at : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRMy5B3dD_I